# AWS Step Functions SendSQSMessage: Dynamic MessageGroupId

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am using the AWS CDK to create a state machine that sends a message to a fifo queue and waits for a callback from the lambda worker to continue execution.

I would like the messages that get sent to the fifo queue to have a dynamic MessageGroupId assigned to them so I can control the number of lambda workers processing the messages. The only way I can think of to have a dynamic MessageGroupId is to reference some parameter on the step function input with JsonPath, however I have not come across any documentation about it. My initial tests to use JsonPath to dynamically pass the MessageGroupId failed, simply passing the string "$.MessageGroupId" effectively giving each message the same message group id and thus one lambda worker.

1. Is it possible to dynamically assign a message group id to a sqs message when sent from a step function?
2. If so, how?

Comment: Having the same problem here. Trying to access both the Context object ($$) and input ($) object in the `MessageGroupId` field would result with the literal string. For Example, setting `MessageGroupId` to `$$.TaskToken` would results with literary the string `$$.TaskToken` and not its value. According to the docs, you should be able to access intrinsic-functions since `MessageGroupId` is nested within `Parameters` field - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html but that didn't worked either.

Answer (score 1):

With the help AWS Support, I managed to do it by either using the [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) or passing an ID from the initial input and reference it with `$`.

Here's an example:

```
{
  "Comment": "Generate unique MessageGroupId",
  "StartAt": "Start",
  "States": {
    "Start": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "TimeoutSeconds": 60,
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sqs:sendMessage.waitForTaskToken",
      "Parameters": {
        "QueueUrl": "<YOUR_QUEUE_URL>",
        "MessageBody": {
          "Input.$": "$",
          "TaskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
        },
        "MessageGroupId.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

My problem was that I was trying to `MessageGroupId` like so:

`"MessageGroupId": "$$.Execution.Id"`

Where I should have done:

`"MessageGroupId.$": "$$.Execution.Id"`

Appending `.$` would resolve the expression `"$$.Execution.Id"` instead of putting literally the string `"$$.Execution.Id"`.

Comment: And If you are using CDK then you need to give JsonPath.StringAt("$$.Execution.Id"). Thank you for the answer.